# how to make formulas on a column by setting conditions for another column

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet, drive

I am working on drive for Excel files, and I need to make calcs like sums and counts for totals BUT the problem I have is setting conditions.
These conditions are in other columns different from which where I have to make the operations.

you can see better my problem in this picture
[image]

as you can see I need the the following formulas

- B61:  how much cells are with text "x" in range B51:B60
- D61:  the sum of hours in range D51:D60 BUT only for cells that have "x" in column B
- C62:  how much cells are with text "x" in range C51:C60
- D62:  the sum of hours in range D51:D60 BUT only for cells that have "x" in column C
- B63:  how much cells are without text in range B51:C60
- D63:  the sum of hours in range D51:D60 BUT only for cells that are in blank in column B and bland in column C

Can anyone can tell me which formulas should I use?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array formula.  Something like this:

`=SUM(IF(B1:B9="x",D1:D9))`

after typing the formula hold control + shift + enter to create the array formula.  Once you do that it should put {} around your formula.  `B1:B9` is the range with the x's and `D1:D9` is the values you would like to total.

[Here's a link to more information about array Formulas.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7)